# Activity is started but not displayed

Tags: android, android-intent, android-activity

Here is the scenario:
There are two activities; activity A (the main activity) and activity B. Generally activity B is launched by Activity A and everything is normal. Also activity B can launch other B activities. Any B activities that are launched have their flag set to Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK.
Sometimes when browsing B activity from outside the app, something unusual happens. The first B activity, say B1, is launched, but when trying to launch another B activity, say B2, from within B1 nothing happens and I need to restart the application to work properly.
When I checked logcat's ActivityManager tag, in normal scenario there are two line of log; one says (activity) STARTED and the other says DISPLAYED. But in the buggy scenario it just says STARTED.

Comment: Did you call **setContentView();** inside your B activities?

Comment: @Rami yes, it is called.

Comment: Post your code (the intent that starts the activity B, and the activity B code "onCreate" method)

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure, but I think the problem may be your 'FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK'.

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html#FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK

> When using this flag, if a task is already running for the activity
>   you are now starting, then a new activity will not be started;
>   instead, the current task will simply be brought to the front of the
>   screen with the state it was last in.

Answer (score 0):

You must set the contentView to the XML file inside your activity that is not showing. Like this: setContentView(R.layout.yourXMLLayout);